# Fetch unique values from a field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this document structure :

```
[
{
   "uuid":1,
   "data":{....},
   "date":"2020-10-10T23:00:00"
},
{
   "uuid":1,
   "data":{....},
   "date":"2020-10-10T23:00:00"
},
{
   "uuid":1,
   "data":{....},
   "date":"2020-10-10T23:00:00"
},
{
   "uuid":2,
   "data":{....},
   "date":"2020-10-10T23:00:00"
},
{
   "uuid":2,
   "data":{....},
   "date":"2020-10-10T23:00:00"
}
]
```

How can I write a query that returns the uuids. for above example I want this result:

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Docs are nested ?

Comment: No its not nested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation based on `uuid` field:

A working example:

**Mappings**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "uuid": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "date": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Insert some documents:**

```
POST my_index/_doc/1
{
   "uuid":1,
   "date":"2020-10-10T23:00:00"
}
POST my_index/_doc/2
{
   "uuid":1,
   "date":"2020-10-10T23:00:00"
}
POST my_index/_doc/3
{
   "uuid":2,
   "date":"2020-10-10T23:00:00"
}
POST my_index/_doc/4
{
   "uuid":2,
   "date":"2020-10-10T23:00:00"
}
```

**Search query:**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "uuids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "uuid",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "uuids" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "2",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The `key` field inside `buckets` is the `uuid` value.